# Plotting implicit function using fsolve

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, lambda

I am trying to plot an implicit function using scipy.fsolve but cant seem to get it to work.
I want to plot the function z(x,y) where x + y + z + sin(z) = 0 using scipy.fsolve.

```
import numpy as np

import scipy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x,y: scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda z: x + y + z + np.sin(z), x0 = 0).tolist()[0]

x = np.linspace(-1,1,50)

y = np.linspace(-1,1,40)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 

Z = f(X,Y)

fig =plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

`
This gives me "_minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats".

I dont see why this would be since I can call the function on individual values and its return type is float. It seems like the controversial line is Z = f(X,Y).

Thankful for any help!

**EDIT**
The original error is fixed for the most part however

```
def z_func(x, y): z_solve = scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda z: x + y + z + np.sin(z), x0=np.zeros_like(x))
return z_solve.tolist()[0] 

x = np.linspace(-1,1,50) 
y = np.linspace(-1,1,40) 

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
X = X.reshape(-1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1) 
Z = z_func(X,Y)
fig =plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')  
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

now gives me AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: I've never used Lambda functions before, so I don't know what's going on there, but I can spot a few issues: (1) `f` is not properly defined as a function. You need a `def f(x, y):` somewhere. (2) You aren't plotting anything. (3) You probably want a 3D plot, so you will need a `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')` and `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)`. I will post a full answer once I figure out the lambda function part.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It might help me understand how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ` This gives me "_minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats".

This is because you're sending 2D arrays (`X` and `Y`) in the `fsolve` function. Try reshaping `X` and `Y` before the `f()` call.

```py
X = X.reshape(-1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1)
```

You'll come across a second error because the `x0` is set to a unique `0` value while it should have the same shape as `X` and `Y`. Here is an example (you can flat it as a lambda function if you want):

```py
def z_func(x, y):
    z_solve = scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda z: x + y + z + np.sin(z), x0=np.zeros_like(x))
    return z_solve.tolist()[0]
```

---

*EDIT following the additional information provided in the comments section*

To plot a 3D wireframe, you will `X`, `Y` and `Z` inputs to be 2D arrays. So the steps would be:

- keep the 2D shape of either `X` or `Y` (same ones) outputted by the `meshgrid` function,
- flatten `X` and `Y` to get all positions and compute Z for each position.
- reshape `X`, `Y` and `Z` to the initial 2D shape
- call `ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)`

```py
# [...]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
grid_shape = X.shape  # same has Y.shape

# Flatten X and Y to get all possible positions
X = X.reshape(-1) 
Y = Y.reshape(-1) 
positions = np.dstack([X, Y])[0]

# Compute Z values for each position
Z = np.array([f(xpos, ypos) for xpos, ypos in positions])

# Reshape everything to be plotted in 3D axis
X = X.reshape(grid_shape)
Y = Y.reshape(grid_shape)
Z = Z.reshape(grid_shape)

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d') 
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color = 'red')
```

You should get the following figure :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, seem to solves most of the problem however
` def z_func(x, y):
  z_solve = scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda z: x + y + z + np.sin(z), x0=np.zeros_like(x))

    return z_solve.tolist()[0]


x = np.linspace(-1,1,50)

y = np.linspace(-1,1,40)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 

X = X.reshape(-1)

Y = Y.reshape(-1)

Z = f(X,Y)

fig =plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color = 'red')

plt.show()
 `
now gives me AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: following [@Jacob Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7107322/jacob-ivanov) comment, please give us more information about what you're trying to plot.

Comment: I want to plot the function z(x,y) where x + y + z(x,y) + sin(z(x,y)) = 0 using scipy.fsolve in a 3D graph.

Comment: @flowerlilypad I've updated to answer to my best understanding of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I want. Does not seem to work for me though. When I run it I get "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (40,50)"

Comment: Did you change `Z` to be `Z = np.array([f(xpos, ypos) for xpos, ypos in positions])` ?